# 16.40LT boot win usb inserted

Tags: boot, usb

Booting from 16.04 DT, normally is with out event, however with my 64gb USB Inserted (not booting or install from), after the bios boot the computer hangs at a black screen with a blinking text cursor and will not load, although it will reboot.  Removing the usb drive and rebooting the computer loads as it should, about 5 seconds.

Would someone please direct me to the proper resource on my computer that will detail this anomaly or if you know of a similar experience would you please forward the details to me.

Thank you in advance for your help and peace be yours,
Stan Ralph

Comment: Sounds like your flash drive is A) on the top of the list of things to be booted in your BIOS, or B) marked as "Bootable"

Comment: It was indeed a boot config problem.  Even though in the bios, this ASRock board was set to Sata hd as 1st, and Sata CD Rom as second, when the usb drive is inserted it shows up as boot option 4 and boot option 3.  I have disabled those two boot options and all is back to normal. Thanks for your comment and peace be upon you....

Comment: Can you please put the solution that worked for you as an answer and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BIOS, reorder the list of boot devices.  Adding the temporary usb disk causes the boot device (sda) to be placed off the active boot disk and I believe the time element required for bios to search the usb drive for suitable boot was in process and I terminated assuming the computer had hung up.  My mistake with the BIOS configuration and I've been doing this stuff for 35+ years....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your flash drive is A) on the top of the list of things to be booted in your BIOS, or B) marked as "Bootable".

You need to correct your boot order so that your USB is not at the top of the devices meant to be booted.